# How to add in if else statement to validate for string

Tags: java, if-statement, bluej

I am using BlueJ for this assignment I have and I have a problem doing this part of the question which is to put decision constructs to ensure that invalid data is not set which I have already tried.In which I placed the if else statement in
the setName portion which does not work. The code will show error if I have put 1 in the GraphicIllustrators main void portion for setName. So where do I need to put the if else statement in the code below.BTW I am using inheritance to do this.So please advise.Thanks!

The coding for the main class:

```
public class Publishing_Inc
    {
        private int ID=0;
        private String name="-Name Needed-";
        private int level=0;
        private String jobtitle="-Title Needed-";
        private String edit="-Edit Skill-";

public void calculateID(){
    int uniqueID;
    uniqueID =((int)( Math.random()*10000)+1);
    ID = uniqueID;
}
public int getID(){
    return ID;
}



 public void setName(String d) {
name = d;
}
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setTitle(String b){
    jobtitle=b;
}
public String getTitle() {
return jobtitle;
}

public void calculatelevel(){
    int uniquelevel;
    uniquelevel =((int)( Math.random()*3)+1);
    level = uniquelevel;
}
public int getlevel() {
return level;
}

public void setEdit(String z){
    edit=z;
}
public String getEdit() {
return edit;
}
```

}

The sub class:

```
public class GraphicIllustrators extends Publishing_Inc
{
    public void displayGraphInformation() {
System.out.println("ID: " + getID());
System.out.println("Name:" + getName());
System.out.println("Job Title: " + getTitle());
System.out.println("Level: " + getlevel());
System.out.println();
}

 public static void main (String args[]) {
 GraphicIllustrators graphic = new GraphicIllustrators ( );
graphic.calculateID ( );
graphic.setName (" Tim Cook" );
graphic.calculatelevel ();
graphic.setTitle ("Graphic Illustrators" );
graphic.displayGraphInformation( );
}

}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with javascript?

Comment: where is your if else? "In which I placed the if else statement in the setName portion which does not work. "

Comment: Please post the relevant code. There is no problem with `graphic.setName (" Tim Cook" );`.

Comment: `graphic.setName(1);` will raise a compile time error and there is no way an `if` statement can help you here. The compiler checks the types of passed variables/literals and they do not match the required type, then the compiler will raise a corresponding error. You can try to cast the  variable to the needed type, but I don't see the point in doing this here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void main (String args[]) {
      GraphicIllustrators graphic = new GraphicIllustrators ( );
      graphic.calculateID ( );

      if (input instanceof String) {
           graphic.setName ( input ); //where input comes from an input box or query or other source.
      }
      else
      {
         //alert the user.
      }
      graphic.calculatelevel ();
      graphic.setTitle ("Graphic Illustrators" );
      graphic.displayGraphInformation( );
 }
```

When you pass an argument to the function `setName` that isn't a `String`, Java will throw an exception. You need to cast the object sent to a string. If you want to prevent this, you should check the input before it's send the function `setName`. This will check if the input is an instance of the Object `String`, if not alert the user.

Comment: I dont know from where you have this main(from TO not) but your instanceof is wrong. And what is input?

Comment: @pL4Gu33, I don't know precisely what the OP wants to check, but it seems he wants to check if the input sent to `setName` is a string, however he uses a typed string as input, so I made up the input variable to simulate user input. (Also deleted the `=` was a typo).

Comment: @Tom, You're right. Was trying to make an example that uses user input, deleted the confusing input variable and added a comment to the line invoking `setName`

Comment: The only way this will work is, then `input` is of type `String`. If it is something else, like `Object`, then you still need to *cast* it. You already checked that it contains a String, so it won't cause any harm to do so.